# How can I know if a certain service is running or not?

Tags: services, sysv

The **service** utility allows to know the current status for the services installed in the system.

However, when invocking **service --status-all** some services are listed as [+] (running), some as [-] (stopped) and some as [?] (unknown?).
How can I know wether a certain service (from those marked as [?]) is running or not?

Maybe I could say that I **don't need** to use the **service** utility, just some mechanism to know which services are effectively running and which not.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo service foo status
```

See man service [manpage for the `service` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/service)

Comment: And why would it be that for some services that does not yield any output?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the service's name, then a regular-privileged user and of course root can use `ps`. My personal favorite is to `ps -ef | grep <service-name-I-am-searching-for>`.